# Is there an equivalent to the default source, when using SetupIntent & PaymentIntent?

Tags: stripe-payments, psd2

With the Sources API, every customer had a `default_source`, but when using `SetupIntent` (in order to be compliant with the PSD2/SCA directive), there doesn't seem to be any direct equivalent.

So my question is, how this can be properly represented API-side (without using `metadata`)?

The [payment_methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object) listing seems to have a property called `preferred` for the `card` (which seems to be what I am looking for), but so far I have not found out, how to get/set this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to the `default_source` for Payment Methods and the newer APIs like Setup Intents and Payment Intents.  The closest thing is [`invoice_settings.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method), but it only applies to Invoices.

To answer your question directly, you have three choices:

1. Set and use the value of `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`, specifying the Payment Method stored there explicitly for each Setup and Payment Intent
2. Specify the default Payment Method in `metadata` as you suggested
3. Store the default on your end in your own database

Regarding the `preferred` property, if you're referring to [`card.networks.preferred`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-networks-preferred) that is the preferred card network of the card in question and is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Webhooks, you can listen for **payment_method.attached** or **setup_intent.succeeded** events and set it as default when they are fired.

For more info:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types

Payment method object can be set to update Customer invoice_settings property with a default payment method.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings